# Одновременный запуск нескольких обработчиков событий в Telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

Возможен ли одновременный запуск нескольких обработчиков Newmessage в Telethon по одному для каждого чата?

Comment: видимо, у вас что-то не получется. ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Возможен:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=("d253")))
    ....

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=("d254")))
   ....
```

Где-то видел что чаты можно писать через запятую, каждый в кавычках, но не делал так ибо у меня в каждый чат отдельный функционал был

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]